# Regex greater than zero with 2 decimal places

Tags: regex, decimal

I need a RegEx for a numeric value with up to two decimal places greater than zero and may or may not have a zero in the ones column. I should also add....whole numbers are fine.  See somments below but there could be leading or trailing white spaces

```
Good values:
.1
0.1
1.12
123.12
92
092
092.13

Error values:
0
0.0
0.00
00
1.234
-1
-1.2
Anything less than zero
```

Comment: Just to check: decimal places must not contain `0` and can vary from `1-2` places or `0-2` places? (or put differently: is the `.nn` part optional?

Comment: yes...the .nn part is optional. So whole numbers are allowed. I added that to the question. THx

Comment: Where are the numbers to be found? Would they be the only content of a string, or enclosed in whitespace? This is crucial to match `92` and the like.

Comment: They could potentially be enclosed in white space....and the numbers are the only content of the string

Answer (score 73, accepted):

How about this:

```
^\s*(?=.*[1-9])\d*(?:\.\d{1,2})?\s*$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^            # Start of string
\s*          # Optional whitespace
(?=.*[1-9])  # Assert that at least one digit > 0 is present in the string
\d*          # integer part (optional)
(?:          # decimal part:
 \.          # dot
 \d{1,2}     # plus one or two decimal digits
)?           # (optional)
\s*          # Optional whitespace
$            # End of string
```

Test in Python:

```
>>> import re
>>> test = [".1", "0.1", "1.12", "123.12", "92", "092", "092.13", "0", "0.0", "0.00", "00", "1.234", "-1", "-1.2"]
>>> r = re.compile(r"^\s*(?=.*[1-9])\d*(?:\.\d{1,2})?\s*$")
>>> for item in test:
...     print(item, "matches" if r.match(item) else "doesn't match")
...
.1 matches
0.1 matches
1.12 matches
123.12 matches
92 matches
092 matches
092.13 matches
0 doesn't match
0.0 doesn't match
0.00 doesn't match
00 doesn't match
1.234 doesn't match
-1 doesn't match
-1.2 doesn't match
```

Comment: That's way close.  Only thing it doesn't all ow is .9 with no leding zero.  The user doesn't like having to type in the zero.

Comment: @MikeTWebb: It does allow .9 - why do you think it doesn't?

Comment: @ridgerunner: Thanks :) Guess what I'm doing right now? I've taken over the German translation of EditPadPro (since it's now 7 months since version 7 came out, and I didn't want to wait any longer), and I'm nearly done. (working on the "Tips of the day" now - which nobody ever reads anyway :) Shame, though, they're really good)

Comment: Hi fellas...hate to rain on the parade but the above expression allows 0 and more than 2 decimals.

Comment: @MikeTWebb: No, it doesn't. Show me how it does.

Comment: Maybe we're using differing technologies.  I'm using this as a RegularExpression annotation to a property on an MVC3 C# Model.  When I type in 0 the validation allows it.  Maybe I messed something up

Comment: Dude...my bad. I didn't clean my build. You're right. The RegEx is working spot on! Sorry about that and thanks for the help

Comment: Tim - Actually, I _do_ read those tips! And I always read the manual from cover to cover. That's the only way I've found to learn about all the cool features hidden under the hood. (e.g. triple clicking, CTRL+[, etc..) p.s. Being a regex/epp guy, you might want to check out my enhanced color syntax schemes which provide matching bracket navigation and highlighting _inside regular expressions_. They recognize the full PCRE flavor and correctly show nested groupings, and comments. They are the schemes that have "JMRware" appended to their names. So far I've done PHP, JavaScript and HTML.

Comment: My HTML color scheme highlights the contents of tags having `class="regex"` or `class="regex_x"` as a PCRE regex with and without the `'x'` modifier respectively. I added this to compliment another of my projects: [Dynamic (?:Regex Highlighting)++ with Javascript!](http://jmrware.com/articles/2010/dynregexhl/DynamicRegexHighlighter.html). This is a JavaScript script that provides matching bracket highlighting for browsing regular expressions displayed on a web page. You may want to check that out too.

Comment: How to allow commas for the regular expression mentioned above i.e for the decimal numbers greater than zero? ex: 123,45.67. Will this work: ^\s*(?=.*[1-9,])\d*(?:\.\d{1,2})?\s*$

Comment: No, that won't work (as you can easily test yourself). You could use `^\s*(?=.*[1-9])[\d,]*(?:\.\d{1,2})?\s*$`, but that would also allow `1,2,3.45` or `,,,,,1` and other nonsensical numbers.

Comment: @TimPietzcker - You seem to be the only one that actually tested their answer!

Comment: What if I don't allow leading 0 e.g. 09.23 is not allowed?

Comment: @stt106: You could add a `(?!=0\d)` after the `\s*` part to specifically exclude this.

Answer (score 6):

The code below allows both `,` and `.`.

```
^(?=.*[1-9])[0-9]*[.,]?[0-9]{1,2}$
```

Answer (score 1):

`/^[0-9]*(\.{1})?([0-91-9][1-9])?$/`

try this it passes all your cases

Comment: This (incorrectly) doesn't match `.1`, `0.1` and (incorrectly) matches `0`, `00`

Answer (score 0):

`[0-9]+\.[0-9]{1,2}`

That will find:

- At least one number
- A decimal point
- One or two digits after the decimal point.

Comment: This allows 0.0 and doesn't allow integers.

Comment: Also allows `0.00` (incorrectly) and disallows `.1` (incorrectly)

Answer (score -3):

This expression will not allow any white spaces in beginning and last

```
/^\d*(?:\.\d{1,2})*$/
```

Comment: This matches: `0`, `0.0`, `0.00`, `00` (all of which were negative test cases given in the question).

Comment: ^(([1-9]+([.][0-9]{1,3})?)|(0[.][0-9]{2}[1-9]))$   think this will mach the condition

Comment: The new pattern in your comment (incorrectly) fails to match `.1`, `0.1`, `092`, `092.13`, and (incorrectly) matches `1.234`

Comment: Test your regex before post as answer. There is a plenty online regex tester like https://regexr.com/