# Regular Expression for any number greater than 0?

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a way to check if a number is greater than 0 using regex.

For example:

- `12` would return true
- `0` would return false.

Comment: Why does it have to be a regular expression? That's a bad tool to use for this job

Comment: Gareth, in some instances, google analytics allows you to use only regex or exact match ;-)

Answer (score 193, accepted):

I don't know how MVC is relevant, but if your ID is an integer, this BRE should do:

```
    ^[1-9][0-9]*$
```

If you want to match real numbers (floats) rather than integers, you need to handle the case above, along with normal decimal numbers (i.e. `2.5` or `3.3̅`), cases where your pattern is between 0 and 1 (i.e. `0.25`), as well as case where your pattern has a decimal part that is 0. (i.e. `2.0`).  And while we're at it, we'll add support for leading zeros on integers (i.e. `005`):

```
    ^(0*[1-9][0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?|0+\.[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*)$
```

Note that this second one is an Extended RE.  The same thing can be expressed in Basic RE, but almost everything understands ERE these days.  Let's break the expression down into parts that are easier to digest.

```
    ^(
```

The caret matches the null at the beginning of the line, so preceding your regex with a caret anchors it to the beginning of the line. The opening parenthesis is there because of the or-bar, below. More on that later.

```
      0*[1-9][0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?
```

This matches any integer *or* any floating point number above 1.  So our `2.0` would be matched, but `0.25` would not.  The `0*` at the start handles leading zeros, so `005 == 5`.

```
                              |
```

The pipe character is an "*or-bar*" in this context.  For purposes of evaluation of this expression, It has higher precedence than everything else, and effectively joins two regular expressions together. Parentheses are used to group multiple expressions separated by or-bars.

And the second part:

```
                               0+\.[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*
```

This matches any number that starts with one or more `0` characters (replace `+` with `*` to match zero or more zeros, i.e. `.25`), followed by a period, followed by a string of digits that includes at least one that is not a `0`.  So this matches everything above `0` and below `1`.

```
                                                    )$
```

And finally, we close the parentheses and anchor the regex to the end of the line with the dollar sign, just as the caret anchors to the beginning of the line.

Of course, if you let your programming language evaluate something numerically rather than try to match it against a regular expression, you'll save headaches *and* CPU.

Comment: Hi. issue: Its validating 123asd, 123.12kasdf

Comment: @Vineet'DEVIN'Dev, issue resolved. (Thanks, btw.) The RE now includes enclosing parentheses, as most parsers appear to weigh the or-bar higher than null anchors.

Comment: hi ghoti, can i allow comma in this following pattern ^(0*[1-9][0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?|0+\.[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*)$. like for eg: 1000.00 is 1,000.00 and 12324.56 is 12,324.56

Comment: The regex in my answer (which you copied into your comment) does not support commas as thousands separators. You could match that pattern in a regex if you wanted to, but I would suggest that these commas are not actually part of the *number*, but part of the *presentation*. Also, when writing code to handle numbers, you'll need to take into account localization; some places use commas as the radix character and periods as thousands separators, or none at all. This is a bigger problem than one regex can solve.

Comment: Hi, it is neither validating these cases: 00, any negative number, any number with explicit indication of being positive (e.g., +1), any expression without explicit numbers after the period (e.g., 1.), and neither or cases such as -.5, all of which are usually considered valid numbers in C. Slightly changing the regular expression string helps on these cases: ^\+*\-*(0*[0-9][0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?|0*+\.[0-9]*)$

Comment: @NotANumber - well, your first case and any negative would be because the question above mentioned "any number greater than 0". :)  For explicit positive, yes, you could add `[+]?` before the opening parenthesis, but the regex you propose definitely doesn't meet the needs expressed in the question.

Comment: @Ghoti, yes, you are right.

Comment: Regarding the first solution, it could be written even shorter: `^[1-9]\d*$`. By the way, thanks for great answer!

Comment: @DamianBartosik, thanks for your feedback! Since I didn't know what "MVC" was in the question, I didn't know whether the OP's parser understood the shortcuts of enhanced basic REs, so I answered in the most basic form I knew. You will find that even amongst normal tools, RE rules vary. The `\d` shortcut is supported by grep, but not by awk or sed (even the GNU varieties).

Answer (score 19):

What about this: `^[1-9][0-9]*$`

Comment: You're not considering negative numbers.

Comment: @m0skit0 and you're not considering the question: `"Looking to validate that an ID on my model is greater than 0 on submit."`

Comment: Yes, he's looking to **validate** the input is greater than 0 with this regex. This doesn't validate that. It only validates it is not 0.

Comment: Using ASP.NET MVC model validators. Meaning if the regex doesn't match, the input doesn't validate.

Comment: Now with your `^$` edit it indeed does work.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you were saying. I believe at the time I was assuming the user would know to wrap the regex in begin/end symbols. This is better. Thanks :)

Comment: The regex was fine without the anchors.  The ASP.NET RegularExpressionValidator always treats the regex as if it were anchored at both ends.

Comment: "01" is not accepted but "01" is non zero

Comment: @AliAhmed The answer can be easily adjusted to account for leading zeroes, but personally I would assume that is a formatting or input issue and not an intended use case.

Answer (score 14):

Another solution for integer:

```
^[1-9]\d*$
```

`\d` equivalent to `[0-9]`

Comment: This answer does not qualify for the requirement of question. Is 0.1 > 0 or not ? but surely it will work for value>0.

Answer (score 5):

Code:

```
^([0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?|[0]+\.[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*)$
```

Example: http://regexr.com/3anf5

Reference: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/17089c0f-f9cb-437a-9667-ba8329681624/regular-expression-number-greater-than-0?forum=regexp

Answer (score 4):

I think the best solution is to add the + sign between the two brackets of regex expression:

```
^[1-9]+[0-9]*$
```

Comment: How sure are you that this does anything close to what the OP wanted? And why the less-efficient `[1-9]+[0-9]*` instead of what's in the accepted answer?

Answer (score 2):

If you only want non-negative integers, try:
`^\d+$`

Answer (score 1):

I Tried this one and it worked for me for all decimal/integer numbers greater than zero

Allows white space: `^\s*(?=.*[1-9])\d*(?:\.\d{1,2})?\s*$`

No white space: `^(?=.*[1-9])\d*(?:\.\d{1,2})?$`

Reference: [Regex greater than zero with 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609714/regex-greater-than-zero-with-2-decimal-places)

Comment: for once i only copy-paste. Not understanding anything.

Answer (score 0):

there you go:

```
MatchCollection myMatches = Regex.Matches(yourstring, @"[1-9][0-9]*");
```

on submit:

```
if(myMatches.Count > 0)
{
   //do whatever you want
}
```

Comment: answer has been fixed...

Comment: You're not considering negative numbers.

Comment: @m0skit0 read op's question again. its GREATER THAN 0

Comment: YOUR REGEX must make sure it is greater than 0 and IT DOES NOT. Negative numbers are NOT GREATER THAN 0. Maybe you'll understand better with an example: what happens if the user inputs `-156`? Your regex says it's OK when it's definitely not OK.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below expression:

```
(^\d*\.?\d*[1-9]+\d*$)|(^[1-9]+\.?\d*$)
```

Valid entries: 1  1.  1.1  1.0 all positive real numbers

Invalid entries: all negative real numbers and 0 and 0.0

Answer (score 0):

Simplified only for 2 decimal places.

```
^\s*(?=.*[1-9])\d*(?:\.\d{1,2})?\s*$
```

Ref: https://www.regextester.com/94470

Answer (score -1):

The simple answer is:   `^[1-9][0-9]*$`

Comment: What is the added value to other answers?

Comment: I simply search it for my urgent work & that time my head was almost empty, then I got this post but every answer of here is complicated, may for upper-level people need it. But I need a simple solution, not a complex one. So, I just added it for someone like me may be getting help.

Comment: It is exactly the first line of the accepted answer.

Comment: The first answer is huge, like an essay with some paragraph. but I need a simple.

Comment: @MRJaman, the point of StackOverflow is to help people learn, not just to provide free programming services. By providing an answer like this that people will copy-and-paste rather than the accepted answer with its explanations, you may actually *discourage* learning.

Answer (score -2):

I think this would perfectly work :

```regex
([1-9][0-9]*(\.[0-9]*[1-9])?|0\.[0-9]*[1-9])
```

Valid:

```
 1
 1.2
 1.02
 0.1 
 0.02
```

Not valid :

```
0
01
01.2
1.10
```

Comment: Zota, the criterion in the question was to validate a number "*greater than 0*". While I freely admit I am not a mathematician, I'm pretty sure that all of your "not valid" results except the first would evaluate to greater than zero.

Comment: Well tell me when was the last time when you used 0 in front of any other number, you dont count 01 02 03 04... neither the 1,100 because the after zeros are pretty unnecessary.. I forced my brain for 2 hours to build that regex for someone who might need it as I, and the validity refers to that regex ONLY.. Thank you for your feedback even if it was a troll one..

Comment: LOL!!! *"Say, 1.10 is greater than 0"* --- *"WHAT! I squeezed my brain for 2hrs! You troll!"*

Answer (score -3):

```
[1-9]\.\d{1,2}|0\.((0?[1-9])|([1-9]0?)){1,2}\b
```

Comment: An explanation would be nice.

Answer (score -7):

Very simple answer to this use this:    \d*

Comment: That will also match 0, 00, 000, 0000 etc.