# javascript - text input how to accept only positive whole numbers only

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How can I validate a textbox input to allow only whole and positive numbers ?

Comment: You already have the mechanism, and only need the regular expression? If so, the answer is in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038522/regular-expression-for-any-number-greater-than-0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the HTML5 input type="number", you can set min=1 and no max and it will only allow positive whole numbers.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_number

EDIT: If you just want to use JavaScript, you could try something like this:

```
if (Number.isInteger(num) && num >= 0) {
    //true
}
```

Comment: thanks but this adds unwanted "spinner" to the texbox