# HTML type number deleting 0 from possible values, but allow -1 and positives?

Tags: html, css, typescript, input

My task would be to set the html input (it has to be type: number) to accept the following values:
-1,1,2,3,4,5,6.....
So basically leaving out the negative numbers with the exception of -1 and also leaving out the number 0.
Here is the code:

```
<input
 [readonly]="isDisabled"
 type="number"
 aria-label="Character limit"
 class="form-control border-0">
```

I have also tried setting to max and min attribute, but you cannot set multiple max and min.

Comment: You could change it type of text and use the `pattern` attribute to use a regex to restrict it to certain numbers. [regular-expression-for-any-number-greater-than-0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038522/regular-expression-for-any-number-greater-than-0)

Comment: Im sorry i did not phrase it correctly. I dont want to validate the input numbers. I would like to show them to the user.