# How to modify the following regex to accept a double array of int and double values greater than 0?

Tags: html, regex, validation

I have a double array string which should accept integers and double values greater than 0.

So far I was able to validate the double array using this regex : pattern="^[[[0-9.,[]]+]]$" but this accepts 0 values and I need it to accept integers and doubles greater than 0.

I went through this but was unable to modify my regex accordingly. [Regular Expression for any number greater than 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038522/regular-expression-for-any-number-greater-than-0)

Example of desired output: [[5,0.05],[10,0.1],[15,0.15],[20,0.2],[25,0.25],[30,0.3],[35,0.35],[40,0.4],[45,0.45],[50,0.5],[55,0.55],[60,0.6],[65,0.65],[70,0.7],[75,0.75],[80,0.8],[85,0.85],[90,0.9],[95,0.95],[100,1]]

Comment: If you want to forbid zero only values, try `^(?!.*(?<![^\][,])0(?:\.0+)?(?![^\][,]))\[\[\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:,\d+(?:\.\d+)?)*](?:,\[\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:,\d+(?:\.\d+)?)*])*]$`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
^(?!.*(?<![^\][,])0(?:\.0+)?(?![^\][,]))\[\[\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:,\d+(?:\.\d+)?)*](?:,\[\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:,\d+(?:\.\d+)?)*])*]$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xtsXw7/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!.*(?<![^\][,])0(?:\.0+)?(?![^\][,]))` - a negative lookahead that fails the string of there is a `0`, or `0.00` (or `0.00000` etc.) that is inside `[`, `]` or `,`
- `\[\[` - a `[[` string
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` - one or more digits and then an optional sequence of a `.` and one or more digits
- `(?:,\d+(?:\.\d+)?)*` - zero or more sequences of a `,` and then one or more digits and then an optional sequence of a `.` and one or more digits
- `]` - a `]` char
- `(?:,\[\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:,\d+(?:\.\d+)?)*])*` - zero or more sequences of a comma, `[`, one or more digits and then an optional sequence of a `.` and one or more digits, and then zero or more sequences of a `,` followed with one or more digits and then an optional sequence of a `.` and one or more digits, and then a `]` char
- `]` - a `]` char
- `$` - end of string.