# how to check if a substring is NOT present in string

Tags: python

In my python code, I want to make sure that `x pause output` does not occur in a string where x is any number greater than 0.

Comment: integer number? or any arbitryry float larger than zero?

Comment: use simple regex

Comment: For any `x` or for a fixed variable `x`? This determines which of the two answers you got is the correct one (regex for any `x`, simple string formatting and `not in` if `x` is fixed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) and do (based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038522/regular-expression-for-any-number-greater-than-0)):

```py
import re

def string_does_not_occur(text):
    # match any integer greater than 0 followed by "pause output"
    expression = "[1-9]\d* pause output"

    # return true if expression is not found in the text
    return re.search(expression, text) is None:
```

E.g.,

```
some_text = "hello 23 pase output world"  # not containing expression

print(string_does_not_occur(some_text))
True

some_text = "hello 38583 pause output world"
print(string_does_not_occur(some_text))
False
```

Comment: The `if`-`else` is redundant, you could just directly `return re.search(expression, text) is None`.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you are trying to achieve.

With an f-string you can directly pass a variable into a string making it more readable. (Using string concatonation with a `+` works too)

The `in` keyword checks if the substring is present in the string.

The `not` keyword negates the boolean.

```py
if f"{x} pause output" not in my_string:
   ...
```

Comment: I do not think this solves the question, which asks for `x` being *any number greater than 0* – which implies to me that the concrete/actual value of `x` is not known beforehand. How would you then fill in `x` in the f-string? Would you iterate over all positive integers/floats? That does not sound feasible to me.

Comment: Yes I've realized this to after I've seen the other answer. I thought `x` would be a known variable instead of literally any number.

Comment: Fair enough – rereading the question, I agree that it can also be understood in your way. Stackoverflow is not always easy :D