# regex for validation of positve numbers including zeros and 2 places after decimal in java?

Tags: java, regex

```
("^\d{1,15}(\.\d{1,2})?$")
```

This is the regex i'm trying to use but java gives syntax error.

```
^(?!(?:0|0\.0|0\.00)$)[+]?\d+(\.\d|\.\d[0-9])?$
```

This one works well for numbers like 00.00, 124.03, 0.13 but not for 0.0 and 0.

please modify the regex so that it accepts the following kind of numbers :

```
123456.00,
12415366.88,
0.23,
0,
0.00,
0.0,
432547,
```

i.e. only postive numbers which include zero and upto 2 places after decimal

Comment: Possible duplicate of [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609714/regex-greater-than-zero-with-2-decimal-places) question except you have to do some modification for 0.

Comment: The compilation error in your first example can be fixed by properly escaping the backslashes in `\d` to `\\d`.  The second regex specifically excludes `0`, `0.0`, and `0.00`.  You should attempt to understand your code before asking questions about it here.

Comment: why do you need to use regex? try something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/50532/how-do-i-format-a-number-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first regex is the best, but remember that in java you must use a *double* backslash to code a literal backslash, so:

```
str.matches("\\d{1,15}(\\.\\d{1,2})?")
```

Note that with `matches()`, you don't need the leading `^` or trailing `$`, because the expression must match the whole string anyway to return true.

The syntax error was probably because `\d` is not a valid escape sequence, whereas `\n` etc is valid.

Answer (score 1):

public class RegexTest {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String regexExpression = "([0-9]+[.]?|[0-9]*[.][0-9]{0,2})";

    // True examples
    System.out.println("123456.00".matches(regexExpression));

    System.out.println("12415366.88".matches(regexExpression));

    System.out.println("0".matches(regexExpression));

    System.out.println("0.0".matches(regexExpression));
    System.out.println("0.00".matches(regexExpression));
    System.out.println("432547".matches(regexExpression));

    System.out.println("00.00".matches(regexExpression));

    System.out.println("124.03".matches(regexExpression));

    // False examples
    System.out.println("124.033".matches(regexExpression));
    System.out.println("-124.03".matches(regexExpression));
}
```

}

Comment: Matches `1.`, matches `.2`, matches `.` too! :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why regex here. You can try in this way

```
  String num="253.65";
    try{
        double d=Double.parseDouble(num);
        if(d==0.0){
            System.out.println("valid");
        }else if(d>0&&(num.split("\\.")[1].length()==2)){
            System.out.println(num+" is valid");
        }else{
            System.out.println(num+" is invalid");
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e){
        System.out.println(num+"is not a valid number");
    }
```

Live [Demo](http://ideone.com/jWfeYt)

Comment: If it's not a valid string representation of a double, an exception will be thrown.

Comment: At this point, regex offers a far more clear and compact solution.