# What is the regex for "Decimal Number except zero"

Tags: regex

I want to match
`\d{0,3}([.,]\d{1,5})?` but without matching stuff like

0.000
00,000
.000
,0000

(No complete zero number) - How do i adjust?

Comment: @imi what about 0.1, or 0.123

Comment: Use [`(0*[1-9][0-9]*([\.,][0-9]+)?|0+[\.,][0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*)`](https://regex101.com/r/Tt4wKl/3/)

Comment: @user3483203 Looks like that does the job. Edit: No it does not. There is no limit on digits anymore 15135.54 is a match and should not. Also .23 is not a match anymore but should be (zero is implied)

Comment: Found the solution here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/8609898/4338278 `(?=.*[1-9])\d{0,3}(?:[\.,]\d{1,5})?`