# TextField doesn't take input after adding 2 decimal positive numbers configuration in whitelistingtextinputformatter

Tags: regex, dart, flutter

```
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                inputFormatters: [
                  WhitelistingTextInputFormatter(
                      RegExp("^\s*(?=.*[1-9])\d*(?:\.\d{1,2})?\s*\$"))
                ],
              ),
```

I'm using this settings in my TextFormField and using this regex which I took from another SO post. Tests seem fine on regex101.com but I can't put any input on my form with this regexp.

My goal with regex is get two decimal positive floating point numbers.

[Regex greater than zero with 2 decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609714/regex-greater-than-zero-with-2-decimal-places)

Comment: Try `RegExp(r"^(?=.*[1-9])\s*\d*(?:\.\d{1,2})?\s*$")`. What are your regex rules, BTW? Maybe `(?=.*[1-9])` is redundant, it requires at least one non-0 digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
RegExp(r"^\s*\d*(?:\.\d{1,2})?\s*$")
       ^                         ^
```

Or, if you want to keep the "at least one non-zero digit in string" requirement (as the regex you tried hints at that):

```
RegExp(r"^(?=.*[1-9])\s*\d*(?:\.\d{1,2})?\s*$")
```

The point here is that:

- You should use a raw string literal for regex escapes to work with a single backslash
- `$` is an end of string anchor only if it is not escaped and is out of square brackets
- The lookahead must be placed after `^` for better performance.

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.*[1-9])` - there must be a non-zero digit after any 0+ chars other than line break chars
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\d*` - 0+ digits
- `(?:\.\d{1,2})?` - an optional sequence of

  - `\.` - a dot
  - `\d{1,2}` - 1 or 2 digits
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `$` - end of string.