# TextFormField clears input text even if the Regex expression is satisfied

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I'm using [`RegExp` for positive decimal numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609714/regex-greater-than-zero-with-2-decimal-places)

```dart
TextFormField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true),
  inputFormatters: [
    FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'^\s*(?=.*[1-9])\d*(?:\.\d{1,2})?\s*$')),
  ],
)
```

But when I enter something like `1.x`, the `TextFormField` deletes the entire input. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the issue is that your regular expression don't give you the ability to have a `.` without a digit after it. you can copy past `x.y` but you can't type it one char at a time.
the solution would be relative to what you want and prioritize, but I think this regex might solve the issue :

```
r'^\s*(?=.*[1-9])\d?\.*(?:\d{1,2})?\s*$'
```

Comment: Thanks, it works but why is that I can't type but I can paste?

Comment: glade it worked, 
in your regex `r'^\s*(?=.*[1-9])\d*(?:\.\d{1,2})?\s*$`, 
`1.3` is allowed
but `1.` is not allowed
so when you are typing `1.3`, and start with `1.` which is not allowed, the text gets cleared before you complete typing `1.3`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But why is that the `TextFormField` clears everything instead of stopping the user from entering any invalid character? Is this desired behavior in Flutter?

Comment: this behavior is happening because you're using `inputFormatter`, if you want the form to not accept something you are letting the user type, you would use `validator` like:

```validator: (value){
            String pattern =
                r'^\s*(?=.*[1-9])\d?\.*(?:\d{1,2})?\s*$';
            RegExp regex = new RegExp(pattern);
            if (!regex.hasMatch(value!))
              return 'this input is not accepted';
            else
              return null;
        
          }```

Comment: I knew the validator part, I thought `inputFormatters` should not let user type in invalid characters instead of clearing the entire text. But thank you once again for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

The `\.\d{1,2}` part matches *two* char sequence, `.` and then one or two digits.

The point here is that you need to allow a `.` char even if there is *zero*, one or two digits. To do this, you need to change `\d{1,2}` to `\d{0,2}`:

```dart
FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'^\s*(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d{0,2})?\s*$'))
```

*Details*:

- `^` -  start of string
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(?:0|[1-9]\d*)` - `0` or a non-zero digit followed with zero or more digits (**NOTE** that this means no `00` or `01` at the start of a number is allowed, but `100` is allowed; also it means the digit must exist in the input, it should be typed in first (deduced from `(?=.*[1-9])` in your pattern))
- `(?:\.\d{0,2})?` - an optional sequence of a `.` and then zero, one or two digits
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `$` - end of string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fJsgmB/1).

**NOTE** that if you want to be able to start typing with whitespace, you need to make `(?:0|[1-9]\d*)` optional with a `?`: `(?:0|[1-9]\d*)?`.