# Regex to match none zero currency (can be positive or negative, can have ',' but cannot be equal to 0)

Tags: regex

I want to have a regular expression to match none zero currency. This currency can be positive value or negative value, can include ',' (such as `1,000` / `1,000,000.00`), but cannot be equal to 0.

For example, the following values are allowed:

```
555
555.00
-888.00
-888
-66,666.00
-66,666
-66,666,777.00
66777888
```

the following values are NOT allowed:

```
0
0.00
-0.00
abc
```

I have a regular expression `^[+-]?[0-9]{1,3}(?:,?[0-9]{3})*(?:\.[0-9]{2})?$`  works for most of the case, but just still allowing equal to 0.

Anyone can help? Thank you very much!

Comment: What is the language or the tool you are using?

Comment: If lookaheads are acceptable: [`^(?![+-]?[0,.]+$)[+-]?[0-9]{1,3}(?:,?[0-9]{3})*(?:\.[0-9]{2})?$`](https://regex101.com/r/NbAWZf/1)

Comment: @markalex, the negative lookahead could be replaced with a positive one: `(?=.*[1-9])`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/K2fXcc/1)

Comment: @CarySwoveland, agree - it would be easier to understand.

Comment: I've found [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609714) for this, but I can't recast my vote to close from "needs clarity" to "duplicate"

Comment: I also wondered if you want to allow e.g. `1,123123.12` if not, [try this regex](https://regex101.com/r/EtfMzO/1). Not sure if it the other changes like no leading zeros are wanted!

Comment: @bobblebubble (aka doublebubble), one could also use lookaheads to disallow certain formatting, as [here](https://regex101.com/r/mDq1HF/1). btw, you wrote, "3.) if starting with 0. no 00". I don't think the OP meant "if starting with 0", merely all zeroes are frowned upon strongly.

Comment: @CarySwoveland double bubbles at least! haha :) Your `(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)` is much simpler than what I wrote there... [updated my demo to it (no more lookaheads at all)](https://regex101.com/r/EtfMzO/2). Regarding *if starting with 0. no 00*, my pattern has a second part `0\.(?:0[1-9]|[1-9]\d` which covers only where string starts with `0` all other cases are treated in the first part.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Regarding your demo, an [idea to use `(?=[^1-9]*[1-9])` instead of `(?=.*[1-9])`](https://regex101.com/r/J7bzCd/1) for reducing steps (I put an `\n` in the Regex101 demo for not skipping lines) - It now has almost the same amount of steps like my latest demo without any lookarounds / your thousands separator snippet.

Comment: Could the string be, "I'm out $550.02 or maybe more", or must the string in question contain the number only, such as "550.02"?

Comment: Thank you very much for all your suggestions and comments. I greatly appreciate it!